# Getting width and height from jpeg image file

Tags: c, height, width, jpeg

I wrote this function to given filename(a jpeg file) shall print its size in pixels, w and h. According to tutorial that I'm reading,

> //0xFFC0 is the "Start of frame" marker which contains the file size 
>   //The structure of the 0xFFC0 block is quite simple [0xFFC0][ushort
>   length][uchar precision][ushort x][ushort y]

So, I wrote this `struct`

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct imagesize {
  unsigned short len; /* 2-bytes */
  unsigned char c;    /* 1-byte */
  unsigned short x;   /* 2-bytes */
  unsigned short y;   /* 2-bytes */
}; //sizeof(struct imagesize) == 7
#pragma pack()
```

and then:

```
#define SOF 0xC0 /* start of frame */

    void jpeg_test(const char *filename)
    {
      FILE *fh;
      unsigned char buf[4];
      unsigned char b;

      fh = fopen(filename, "rb");
      if(fh == NULL) 
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open '%s' file\n", filename);

      while(!feof(fh)) {
        b = fgetc(fh);

        if(b == SOF) {

          struct imagesize img;
    #if 1
          ungetc(b, fh);
          fread(&img, 1, sizeof(struct imagesize), fh);
    #else
          fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fh);
          int w = (buf[0] << 8) + buf[1];
          int h = (buf[2] << 8) + buf[3];
          img.x = w;
          img.y = h;
    #endif

          printf("%dx%d\n",
             img.x,
             img.y);

          break;
        }
      }

      fclose(fh);
    }
```

But I'm getting `520x537` instead of `700x537`, that's the real size.

Can someone point and explain where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A JPEG file consists of a number of sections. Each section starts with `0xff`, followed by 1-byte section identifier, followed by number of data bytes in the section (in 2 bytes), followed by the data bytes. The sequence `0xffc0`, or any other `0xff--` two-byte sequence, inside the data byte sequence, has no significance and does not mark a start of a section.

As an exception, the very first section does not contain any data or length.

You have to read each section header in turn, parse the length, then skip corresponding number of bytes before starting to read next section. You cannot just search for `0xffc0`, let alone just `0xc0`, without regard to the section structure.

[Source](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/).

Comment: +1 Very good explanation, I fell into the same trapp. Minor hint: There are a few sections that don't follow the general scheme, namely SOI (start of image, what you mention, 0xffd8), RSTn (restart marker, 0xffdn, n=0..7) and EOI (end of image, 0xffd9). DRI (0xffdd) follows the scheme, but the length value is always 4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg#Syntax_and_structure

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues to consider, depending on how "universal" you want your program to be. First, I recommend using [libjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg).  A good JPEG parser can be a bit gory, and this library does a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

Next, to clarify *n.m.'s* statement, you have no guarantee that the first 0xFFCO pair is the SOF of interest.  I've found that modern digital cameras like to load up the JPEG header with a number of APP0 and APP1 blocks, which can mean that the first SOF marker you encounter during a sequential read may actually be the image thumbnail.  This thumbnail is usually stored in JPEG format (as far as I have observed, anyway) and is thus equipped with its own SOF marker.  Some cameras and/or image editing software can include an image preview that is larger than a thumbnail (but smaller than the actual image).  This preview image is usually JPEG and again has it's own SOF marker.  It's not unusual for the image SOF marker to be the last one.

Most (all?) modern digital cameras also encode the image attributes in the EXIF tags.  Depending upon your application requirements, this might be the most straightforward, unambiguous way to obtain the image size. The [EXIF standard document](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) will tell you all you need to know about writing an EXIF parser.  ([libExif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/) is available, but it never fit my applications.) Regardless, if you roll your own EXIF or rely on a library, there are some good tools for inspecting EXIF data. [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) is very good tool, and I've also had good luck with [ExifTool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool).

Lastly, pay attention to endianess.  SOF and other standard JPEG markers are big-endian, but EXIF markers may vary.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, the spec states that the marker is 0xFFC0. But it seems that you only ever look for a single byte with the code `if (b==SOF)`

If you open the file up with a hex editor, and search for 0xFFC0 you'll find the marker. Now as long as the first 0xC0 in the file is the marker, your code will work. If it's not though, you get all sorts of undefined behaviour.

I'd be inclined to read the whole file first. It's a jpg right, how big could it be? (thought this is important if on an embedded system) Then just step through it looking for the first char of my marker. When found, I'd use a memcmp to see if the next 3bytes mathed the rest of the sig.

Comment: I would also point that `width` and `height` should be swapped within the above code. In other words `x` (read first) gives the height, and `y` the width. Also to support all kinds of SOF markers (e.g baseline DCT, progressive DCT, etc) one may want to scan all markers between `0xFFC0` and `0xFFCF`: see the [equivalent code in Ruby](https://github.com/sstephenson/dimensions/blob/master/lib/dimensions/jpeg_scanner.rb).

Comment: Good point! While we're at it, don't forget to mention that the dimensions/size are stored in big-endian format. Here's the pertinant bytes from a 320x128px image. ( FF C0 - 00 11 - 08 - 00 80 - 01 40 ) It seems that the x,y coords are packed into a 4byte long before being saved to file. If you load the dimensions as a 4byte int, then change the endianness - you end up with the coords correct and in the x,y order..

Comment: @deltheil I'm unsure about the linked Ruby code. The spec only names 0xffc0..0xffc3 and 0xffc9..0xffcb as SOF markers, while the Ruby code adds 0xffc5..0xffc7 and 0xffcd..0xffcf!?